# Use font awesome animations with custom font

Tags: html, css, wordpress, fonts

I am trying to use the tada animation from [font awesome](http://l-lin.github.io/font-awesome-animation/) with a custom font I generated from [fontastic](http://app.fontastic.me). I have added the [font-awesome-animation.min.css](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/l-lin/font-awesome-animation/master/dist/font-awesome-animation.min.css) to the header of my WordPress theme file. I have also added this html code to my [site](http://www.new.wjmediadesign.com/) (see the membership icon).

```
<a class="faa-parent animated-hover" href="#">
  <div class="service-icon-container">
    <div class="fa icon icon-membership faa-tada"></div>
  </div>
  <h3>Membership</h3>
  <p>Membership info text</p>
  </a>
```

Any suggestions on making it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to change the reference of hover class in css.

for your membership icon try adding following code:

```
a.faa-parent:hover .service-icon-container > .fa.icon {
-webkit-animation: tada 2s linear infinite;
animation: tada 2s linear infinite;}
```

for all other icons, add anchor tag as you added for membership.

Comment: @William - Its my pleasure :P